# Scrape a specific h2 tag inside a div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, emoji

I am trying to scrape the emojis inside the h2 tag 'Events' from http://emojipedia.org/food-drink/. I have written the following code, but the head_links is an empty list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import json
import csv
url2 = "http://emojipedia.org/food-drink/"
html2 = requests.get(url2).content
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
head_links = soup2.findAll('h2', {'class':'Events'})
```

I also tried to use soup.select commands, but again I got an empty list..

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're looking for isn't actually an `h2` tag with the class `Events`, you're looking for a `div` tag that contains an `h2` tag whose *content* is "Events".

This should get you started:

```
div_contents = soup2.find('h2', text='Events').findParent()
```